# How to copy postman history from chrome app to native app?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, postman

Since Google is now ending the support for chrome apps. Recently Postman deprecated their chrome app and introduced a native app.

I am in the process of switching from postman chrome app to native app.

How do I copy the history from my chrome app to native app. Sync doesn't work.
There is a option to export data but that doesn't export the history.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So while searching for this I came across [this](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1647) post which is very helpful.
Thanks to stephan for sharing this code.
Follow these steps to copy your history from chrome app to native app.

```js
//In Chrome DevTools on the background page of the Postman extension...

//A handy helper method that lets you save data from the console to a file
(function(console){

console.save = function(data, filename){

    if(!data) {
        console.error('Console.save: No data')
        return;
    }

    if(!filename) filename = 'console.json'

    if(typeof data === "object"){
        data = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4)
    }

    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/json'}),
        e    = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
        a    = document.createElement('a')

    a.download = filename
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    a.dataset.downloadurl =  ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':')
    e.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null)
    a.dispatchEvent(e)
}
})(console)

//Common error reporting function
function reportError(){
console.error('Oops, something went wrong :-(');
}

//Open the database
var dbReq = indexedDB.open('postman')
dbReq.onerror = reportError;
dbReq.onsuccess = function(){
var db = dbReq.result;

//Query for all the saved requests
var requestReq = db.transaction(["requests"],"readwrite").objectStore('requests').getAll();
requestReq.onerror = reportError;
requestReq.onsuccess = function(){
 var requests = requestReq.result;
 
 //Dump them to a file
 console.save(JSON.stringify(requests), 'postman-requests-export.json')
 console.info('Your existing requests have been exported to a file and downloaded to your computer.  You will need to copy the contents of that file for the next part')
};
};


//Switch to standalone app and open the dev console

//Paste the text from the exported file here (overwriting the empty array)
var data = [] 

//Enter the guid/id of the workspace to import into.  Run the script with this value blank if you need some help
//  finding this value.  Also, be sure you don't end up with extra quotes if you copy/paste the value
var ws = ''; 

//Common error reporting function
function reportError(){
console.error('Oops, something went wrong :-(');
}

//Open the database
var dbReq = indexedDB.open('postman-app')
dbReq.onerror = reportError;
dbReq.onsuccess = function(){
var db = dbReq.result;

if(!data.length){
 console.error('You did not pass in any exported requests so there is nothing for this script to do.  Perhaps you forgot to paste your request data?');
 return;
}

if(!ws){
 var wsReq = db.transaction(["workspace"],"readwrite").objectStore('workspace').getAll();
 wsReq.onerror = reportError;
 wsReq.onsuccess = function(){
  console.error('You did not specify a workspace.  Below is a dump of all your workspaces.  Grab the guid (ID field) from the workspace you want these requests to show up under and include it at the top of this script');
  console.log(wsReq.result);
 }
 return;
}

data.forEach(function(a){
 a.workspace = ws;
 db.transaction(["history"],"readwrite").objectStore('history').add(a);
});

console.log('Requests have been imported.  Give it a second to finish up and then restart Postman')
}
//Restart Postman
```

Note :

1.To Use DevTools on your chrome app you will need to enable following flag in
    `chrome://flags` [image: flag]

2.Then just right click and inspect on your chrome postman app.

3.To User DevTools on your native app ctrl+shift+I (view->showDevTools)

Comment: when I execute the last line (`data.forEach...`), I get this error: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': One of the specified object stores was not found.` I followed every step.

Comment: @Bere I have update the code to reflect new changes.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh. Sorry for the late reply. I get the data as a json in a file. Now I want to import it to another postman chrome extension app in a different computer. Is that possible? Because the above script doesn't seem to work for an extension app.